# Program does not terminate completely

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I am building a face detector in python using opencv, the functions work fine but i realize the process is still running after exiting the program. The window is closed after pressing key 'q', but the program does not terminate completely. When debugging, it says that "Process is finished with exit code -1". Here is the code:

face_detector.py

```
import cv2
import func_Def

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('Haar/haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('Haar/haarcascade_eye.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)



    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        gray_face = cv2.resize((gray[y: y + h, x: x + w]), (110, 110))
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_face)
        for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
            func_Def.draw_box(gray, x, y, w, h)

    cv2.imshow('Face Detection Using Haar-Cascades ', gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Did you try adding `exit()` at the end?

Comment: Yes, but it does not change anything. The program still does not terminate completely.

Comment: This seems fine. Can you share `func_Def`?